# Standard Rails form + Cocoon gem: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.liooo.engineer/blog/2014/11/22/building-multiple-file-upload-form-in-rails-way/) and the author is using Slim. Since I more familiar with standard Rails form, I try to change the slim markup to normal form like so:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <br><br>

  <%= fields_for :user_photos do |photo| %>
    <%= render "user_photo_fields", f: photo %>
    <span class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association "add photo", f, :user_photos %>
    </span>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**_user_photo_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
</div>
```

And, this is my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_photos
    validates_presence_of :name
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_photos, allow_destroy: true
end

class UserPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

And lastly, strong params inside the **users_controller.rb**. I didn't touch the rest methods inside the controller because I'm using `rails g scaffold user name:string` generator.

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, user_photos_attributes: [:id, :photo, :_destroy])
    end
```

[image]

I get this error:

```
undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's just a simple typo - your `fields_for :user_photos` should be `f.fields_for :user_photos` (so that it's properly connected to the parent form).

Comment: After add `f` in front of `fields_for`, I only get the user name field and the nested fields is gone. http://i.imgur.com/DapYxag.png

Comment: Which is normal, because at the moment of creation there are no nested items, unless you create one in the controller, something like `@user.user_photos.build`

Answer (score 0):

please try with this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_photos
  validates_presence_of :name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_photos, allow_destroy: true
end
```

can you try to fix this by removing the f

```
  <div class="nested-fields">
        <div class="field">
            <%= file_field :photo %>
        </div>
        <%= link_to_remove_association "remove" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: can try using  `photo` instead of `f` `<%= link_to_add_association "add photo", photo, :user_photos %>`

Comment: please try the above changes.

Comment: Still get `undefined method 'attr_accessible' for` error that points to this line `attr_accessible :name, user_photos_attributes: [:id, :photo, :_destroy]`

Comment: if you use rails 4.1 then you have to remove the `attr_accessible`. You can use the https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters